# listView builder inside listview builder is not updating list value on button click

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I have a dropdown menu that adds a `Container` in `list`  with `onChange` function, which is displayed by `listview.builder`, and this container has another `ListView.builder` this second list view builder has a list `listParticipantsSelected` displayed and a `button` that adds some value to a list `listParticipantsSelected.add("some value");`that is displayed in the second `ListView.builder`. when I click this button it adds the value but does not show it in the second list view builder when I remove the whole container and add it again from the dropdown it shows the added value but not instantly.

```
 list.add(Container());
```

This list shown on main listview builder

second list view builder code here

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: listParticipantsSelected.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          setState(
                () {
              listParticipantsSelected.add("some value");
            },
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(listParticipantsSelected[index])
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

In this second list view builder hot reload is also not working I have to hit hot restart.
I need to update the inner list instantly.
I tried with the set state but it is not working. I am confused where I am missing something.

**Edited** : **Build method :** It is a long file but related code is here

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Form(
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 500,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      value: "initial value",
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                      items: elements.map((String items) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: items,
                          child: Text(items),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                        if (newValue == 'Participants') {
                          list.add(Container(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  height: 100,
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: listParticipantsSelected.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                        return GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {listParticipantsSelected.add("some value");},
                                            );
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
                                                Text(listParticipantsSelected[index])
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }),
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(child: Container()),
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                                      child: TextButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                content: Column(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Row(
                                                      children: [
                                                        IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.close), // clear text
                                                          onPressed: () {Navigator.pop(context);},
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Expanded(
                                                      child:
                                                          ListView.builder(
                                                              itemCount: listParticipants.length,
                                                              itemBuilder: (BuildContextcontext, int index) {
                                                                return GestureDetector(
                                                                  onTap: () {
                                                                    setState(() {listParticipantsSelected.add(listParticipants[index]);},);
                                                                  },
                                                                  child:
                                                                      Container(
                                                                    child: Row(
                                                                      children: [
                                                                        Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
                                                                        Text(listParticipants[index])
                                                                      ],
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ),
                                                                );
                                                              }),
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            },
                                          );
                                        },
                                        child: Text('Add'),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ));
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: list.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return list[index];
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

```
      var elements = [
    'initial value',
    'Participants',
  ];
  List listParticipantsSelected = ["Name of member"];
  List<Widget> list = [];

  List listParticipants = [
    "Name of member",
    "Name of member"
        "Name of member"
        "Name of member"
        "Name of member"
  ];
```

Comment: Can you include full build method

Comment: I just update the question with build method

Comment: Can you include data as well? form start point that will include all your data

Comment: just update the list I am using with some sample data.

Comment: Check answer section, calling `setState` is the only part was missing

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you were just missing to call `setState` end of `onChanged`

```dart
child: DropdownButton(
  ....
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    if (newValue == 'Participants') {
         list.add(Container(..);
     
          setState(() {}); //this
```

[image]